# import images from a folder created with electron + reactjs

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm using electron with react and am dynamically saving images to a folder and want to show them in the frontend.

Saving images works fine

```
fs.writeFile("./" + timestamp + ".jpg", arg, "binary", (err) => {
if (err) console.log(err);
else {
  console.log("File written successfully\n");
}});
```

This will save an image in the root folder, but the problem is that while it works well in develeopment when an exe is built the root folder changes, it is then saved in the folder where .exe is.
How can I import these images inside react?

When developing this code for importing in react works but after I build the electron app it does not:

```
const images = importAll(
require.context("./", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```